# Custom coloration for matrix in matplotlib

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I have three matrices that I'd like to plot, but the only solution I've come up with is just plotting one after the other, and that leaves me with the last matrix plotted.

```
ax.imshow(mat1, cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
ax.imshow(mat2, cmap='binary', interpolation='nearest')
ax.imshow(mat3, cmap='autumn', interpolation='nearest')  # actual plot
```

What I want is to display all 0s in the three matrices in white, and higher values in different tones depending on the matrix, e.g.: blue, black and red. Also, in that example, red cells would have precedence over black and black over blue. The solution I'm imagining to this is a function that, given a triple (blue, black, red) with the different values for each component, returns the color the cell should be colored, and feed it to a ColorMap, but I really don't know how to do so or if it's even possible.

Every kind of help and even different solutions (that's the most likely to happen) are welcome and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a *fourth* image, with the RGB value at each point a function of the single value of the first three matrixes at the corresponding point? If so, can you produce the algebra to get from three values to the RGB fourth?

Your question suggests confusion about how plotting turns data into colors. A colormap takes single-valued data, normalizes it, and maps it into some named array of colors. 0 values might be mapped to any color, depending on the colormap and the rest of the data.

A bitmap defines (red, green, blue) values at each pixel. Proper bitmaps have header sections, but the data is an (m,n,3) array. `imshow` plots just that array; it expects the RGB values to be in the [0,1] range.

If you have three data matrices, you have to choose how to map the values to RGB values. Here's an example with three kinds of mapping to RGB. The first two rows are dummy data with a range of values, shown either with a colormap or as the simplest RGB representation. The last row shows ways of combining all three dummy matrices into one image using the whole colorspace.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#dummy data
x = 8
y = 15
mat = []
mat.append(np.arange(x * y).reshape((x, y)) / float(x * y) )
mat.append(np.arange(x * y).reshape((y, x)).T / float(x* y))
mat.append(np.arange(y) * np.arange(x)[:,np.newaxis] / float(99))

# NOTE: this data is approximately in the RGB range. If yours isn't, normalize,
# here or in your makeRGB function.
# (The colormap normalizes single-valued data).

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,4), nrows=3, ncols=3,
                        gridspec_kw={'hspace':0.6})

axs[0,0].imshow(mat[0], cmap='Reds', interpolation='nearest')
axs[0,1].imshow(mat[1], cmap='Greens', interpolation='nearest')
axs[0,2].imshow(mat[2], cmap='Blues', interpolation='nearest')
axs[0,0].set_xlabel('Reds Colormap')
axs[0,1].set_xlabel('Greens Colormap')
axs[0,2].set_xlabel('Blues Colormap')

def asOneHue(mat, hue):
    """
    Use a single-valued matrix to represent one hue in a RGB file.'
    """
    RGBout = np.zeros((len(mat),len(mat[0]),3))
    RGBout[:,:,i] = mat
    return RGBout

for i in (0,1,2):
    axs[1,i].imshow(asOneHue(mat[i],i))
axs[1,0].set_xlabel('Reds bitmap')
axs[1,1].set_xlabel('Greens bitmap')
axs[1,2].set_xlabel('Blues bitmap')

# different ways to combine 3 values
def makeRGB0(mats):
    RGBout = np.zeros((len(mats[0]),len(mats[0][0]),3))
    #RGBout = np.ones((len(mats[0]),len(mats[0][0]),3))
    for i in (0,1,2):
        RGBout[:,:,i] = mats[i]
    return RGBout

axs[2,0].imshow(makeRGB0(mat))
axs[2,0].set_xlabel('Color layers')

def makeRGB1(mats):
    RGBout = np.zeros((len(mats[0]),len(mats[0][0]),3))
    i,j,k = RGBout.shape

    for x in range(i):
        for y in range(j):
            RGBout[x,y] = (mats[0][x][y] / 2,
                           mats[1][x][y],
                           1 - mats[2][x][y])
    return RGBout


axs[2,1].imshow(makeRGB1(mat))
axs[2,1].set_xlabel('Algebraic')

def makeRGB2(mats):
    RGBout = np.zeros((len(mats[0]),len(mats[0][0]),3))
    i,j,k = RGBout.shape
    for x in range(i):
        for y in range(j):
            if mats[0][x][y] > .8:
                RGBout[x,y] = (mats[0][x][y],
                               0,
                               0)
            elif mats[1][x][y] > .8:
                    RGBout[x,y] = (0,
                                   mats[1][x][y],
                                   0)
            else:
                    RGBout[x,y] = (mats[0][x][y],
                                   mats[1][x][y],
                                   mats[2][x][y])
    return RGBout

axs[2,2].imshow(makeRGB2(mat))
axs[2,2].set_xlabel('If-else')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I hadn't found in the docs that I could just plot a plain RGB matrix -- this really made my day!

Comment: Cool. I've tripped over parts of this problem myself; I hope the main pitfalls are implicit in these examples.